# c# - navigate url with using iexplore.exe -embedding?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-c++

I navigate an url using c# using;

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
IE.Navigate2("http://example.org");
```

It uses iexplore.exe (Internet explorer) on backend to navigate the url.
But I want the program to use "iexplore.exe -embedding" instead of "iexplore.exe", means that I want to add that command when the program using the iexplore.exe

What is the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run ieexplorer as new process by command line

```
Process.Start("iexplore.exe -embedding " + yourUrl);
```

There is more details
http://www.dotnetperls.com/process

Comment: I know. But I need to use navigate() function on c#. Thats why I wanted to add the exe command.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jacek points out you can run your own process with [whatever CLI flags you want](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826025(v=vs.85).aspx).  Then you just need to use [SHDocVw.ShellWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773974(v=vs.85).aspx) to iterate over all of the existing IE instances to find the one you started.

You have a couple options in this regard, you can cross reference the result of Process.Start()'s [Id property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id(v=vs.110).aspx) to give you a PID, which you can compare with known PID's previously found to find the "new" one.  You can also navigate to a unique URL and filter for that [URL in the ShellWindows() iteration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa752058(v=vs.85).aspx).

If you need to maintain a reference point to that browser across process invocations or despite subsequent user navigation in the browser instance you can also use [PutProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752095(v=vs.85).aspx) to assign it a unique key-value pair that you can reference again and again across multiple host process invocations (the IE window must remain running for this value to persist.)